# Unable to add reference through suggested action in VS Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio

While trying to add a reference to class in a unit testing class, it takes infinitly long time to execute. I am adding the reference through "Suggested action" shortcut.
I've attached an image below. This keeps going on. I have reinstalled VS, but the problem still there.

[image]

Comment: How are you adding reference to a class? Can you mentioned the steps you are following?

Comment: I get this if I add the reference using "Quick Actions", does it work if you add it by clicking on "Add reference" under "Solution explorer"?

Comment: Should be fixed in [16.9.P2](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48679).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that problem too, but in Visual Studio 2019 Professional some time ago. It has been fixed after an update.

Do you have any update to apply?

Anyway you should report the problem to Visual Studio community through the menu:
[image]

This is a boring problem but you can avoid it adding the reference manually using the [Reference manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I'd rather not suggest to report a problem that has been reported many times before. Just as on Stack Overflow, they don't like duplicates there.

Comment: Due to I don't use Community edition, I don't know if the problem has been fixed there. Of course he should verify before open a ticket, I agree with you.